# Can I ask the following question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is it allowed for me to ask the following question on Stack Overflow?

**Where can I find a suitable SparkJob to test performance metrics of spark on a specific system & what's the best way of measuring them?**

Comment: *best way* sounds as opinion based which is an close reason

Comment: And _"where can I find...."_ sounds like an off-site resource request, which is another close reason.

Comment: Nope.​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍

Comment: You *may* be able to ask on Software Recommendations SE, but read their help center first.

Answer (score 12):

Your question has all the signs of being opinion based or asking for an offsite resource. So no, please don't ask that question on main.

It will need much more detail on what you tried and what your system looks like. I'm not familiar with Spark but your question could include a dataset, the specific operation you want to measure, system setup and an actual attempt with a SparkJob.

In your question you can then include what you learned from that attempt, for example: *I see CPU usage is low but I/O is high* and then explain that you expected the opposite result. That question can ask: *Am I using the correct SparkJob or is my method of gathering statistics wrong*.

Answers to that question will be useful for you and future visitors.

Comment: I have only posted the title of the question I was intending to ask. I would have written a detailed description as to what I am trying to measure and for what purpose **(trade-off between containerizing and non-containerizing)**. Also, I want to know the methods used to calculate metrics like response time- memory usage, disk usage etc. Is it just the by calculating the start and end time or some other tool etc. And especially to know are there standard spark-programs used for this purpose. You think even with all that this question is not valid to be asked here?

Comment: @Shabirmean that all sounds as too broad, to be honest.

Comment: Cool :). Thanks Very Much.